# Getting access to class methods after creating an object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I get different class names (String) from external source e.g: reflection.Test1, reflection.Test2, reflection.OtherTest etc.

I need change these classes to new Objects so that I can use all the methods of a given object
I am trying to create a dedicated method:

```
public static <T extends Base> T createObject(String nameOfClass) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(nameOfClass);
        return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    }
```

But when I try to use it:

```
createObject("reflection.Test1").fillTest1();  //I want to use method fillTest1 from Test1.class
or:
createObject("reflection.Test2").fillTest2(); // //I want to use method fillTest1 from Test1.class
```

i get error in IntelliJ:

> Cannot resolve method 'fillTest1' in 'Object'

How to make these methods visible?
IntelliJ gives me access only to methods in Base.class: I can't see method in my Test1.class and Test2.class

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static <T extends Base> T createObject(String nameOfClass) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(nameOfClass);
        return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // ... I get different class names from external source e.g: reflection.Test1, reflection.Test2, reflection.OtherTest etc.
        createObject("reflection.Test2").fillTest1(); //error :(
    }
}
```

Test1.class:

```
package reflection;

public class Test1 extends Base{
    private String name;

    public void fillTest1(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Test2.class:

```
package reflection;

public class Test2 extends Base{
    private String test2;

    public void fillTest2(String test2){
        this.test2 = test2;
    } }
```

Base Class:

```
package reflection;

public class Base {
    public void setBase(){
        System.out.println("Base method");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is important to call your main class the name of the program. Please change "Main" to "ProgramName". This ensures that the java VM wont have issues with duplicate class naming, but more importantly, other programmers will have less trouble identifying that class.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you made `createObject` to use generic type `T`.
However, when you call this method, you never specify what this type should be, therefore compiler has no idea how to infer it.

You can fix it by calling this way (type will be infered from variable type to which you assign ):

```java
       Test2 t2 = createObject("reflection.Test2");
       t2.fillTest2("whatever");
```

or this way (specify type explicitely):

```java
       Main.<Test2>createObject("reflection.Test2").fillTest2("something");
```

Comment: for the universality of the method: is the possibillity to extract name: "Test2 t2" or <Test2> from the input String: "reflection.Test2"?

Comment: No. Object will be of the type `Test2` however issue is not with the object, but with the reference that points to it (in the main method). Type of this reference has to be either explicitly declared or inferred by the compiler from the context. Only then you'll be able to use that reference to call methods from corresponding class.

Comment: Just to be clear: there is no relationship between the `Test2` class used in the caller and the `"reflection.Test2"` string passed to `createObject`. In fact, the “*I return whatever `T` the caller wishes*” promise of the method must be considered fundamentally broken and there should an an “unchecked” warning at the `(Class<T>)` type cast. You could, for example, write `Runnable r = createObject("reflection.Test2"); r.run();` and the compiler wouldn’t object. And what’s the point of accessing `"reflection.Test2"` via Reflection and having a compile-time reference to `Test2` anyway?